# How to find Average form ArrayList in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` and I am storing Time, BID, ASK. And I am unable to find the average of value2 for the elements 1-5 in inner loop and again 2-6, and again 3-7 like wise.

Here is the code (rs is a DB result iterator):

```
List<String> graphData=new ArrayList<String>();
while(rs.next()){
  i++;
  if(i>6){
    graphData.add(rs.getString("TIME"));
    graphData.add(df.format(rs.getFloat("BID")));
    graphData.add(df.format(rs.getFloat("ASK")));

    for (int arr=i-5; arr<i; arr+=3) {
      sum = sum+graphData.get(arr+3));
    }
    avg = sum/5;
    System.out.println(avg );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using your DBMS for calculating the average? (Maybe SQLite won't cound as DBMS, but surely has avg() function.

Comment: I have to do many other things using sqlite, but meanwhile i have to find the avrage. that's whay i'm using list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is that values are added to the list only when `i>6`. The modification of the list should be out of the `if`.

Then there is a problem with the `arr` counter: it is incremented by 3 because you just want to add the ASK elements, but the loop stops when it reaches `i`. It should be `i*3`. Also, you can start from `i==5` instead of `7`, if `i` starts at `0` (can't see in your code).

```
List<String> graphData=new ArrayList<String>();
int i = 0;
while(rs.next()){
  i++;
  graphData.add(rs.getString("TIME"));
  graphData.add(df.format(rs.getFloat("BID")));
  graphData.add(df.format(rs.getFloat("ASK")));

  if(i>=5){
    double sum, avg = 0;
    for (int arr=i*3-13; arr<i*3-1; arr+=3) {
      sum = sum+graphData.get(arr));
    }
    avg = sum/5;
    System.out.println(avg );
  }
}
```

Comment: Another possibility that you may find easier to read is: `for (int arr=i-5; arr<i; arr++) { sum += graphData.get(arr*3+2); }`